# Unknown signal error as I try to kill a process

Tags: node.js, shell, spawn

I am trying to kill a process using the `kill` method in `child_process`. But I get the following error as I try to call the function:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL]: Unknown signal: 18408
```

I am doing as follows:

```
    const ls = spawn('node',['print']);

    ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    ls.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });


    setTimeout(() => {
            ls.kill(ls.pid);
    },4000);
```

What could be the reason for this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kill()` sends a Unix signal.  These are represented by numbers.  You should pass the number of a signal to `kill()`, not the PID.

Try

```
import signal
print(signal.SIGTERM)
```

That probably prints `15` which is the number of the signal TERM (which normally terminates the process it is sent to).

In your program you could call

```
ls.kill(signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: That's correct.  I'm not into node.js and was led to read this Q only by the shell tag.  I didn't even notice the language used here, but the matter was obvious.  See the other answer for more info about correct node.js syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, unlike the Linux `kill()` command, which takes the process pid to kill and a signal as parameters, Nodejs *ChildProcess* `subprocess.kill()` expects only the signal argument (as string according to the documentation).

*[subprocess.kill([signal])](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal)*

That makes sense because the subprocess already knows its pid (the one you get when using `subprocess.pid`) so you don't need to provide it again.

To kill your process, you can pass a valid signal to the `.kill()` method:

```
ls.kill('SIGTERM');
```

Or, you could also simply call the `.kill()` method of your subprocess without any arguments, which is equivalent to call it with the 'SIGTERM' signal.

```
ls.kill()
```